# How to make my app compatible with more versions android?

Tags: android, flutter

I have published an app on playstore, I have a problem. Some recents devices are not compatible with the app. How can I do to change the minimum version required to download the app ? I want my app to be avaible for a lots of devices.

Answer (score 1):

In your app/build.gradle file, you can set the minSdkVersion to what you want to support. You can find the sdk version numbers here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history